# How do I display the menu properly after each user input?

Tags: python

I've been working on this all day and cannot figure out what I'm not understanding 
This simple program should ask for user input until they enter 9 and then the program exits.

There are 3 functions total. def main():, def menu():, and def menuInput():

1)def main():-simply calls menuInput

2)def menu():-displays a menu only

3)def menuInput():-calls the menu to be displayed, accepts user input, tests to make sure a valid number has been entered, Continues to ask the user for input until a valid choice is made, Repeats the menu selection until 9 is selected.

The problem is that the entire menu should be displayed, and then the program asks for the users selection 1-9. If 1 is chosen, it displays the message and shows the menu again, asking for the input.

Here is my code so far with comments based on my understanding or lack of

```
def main():
#calls menu input
  menuInput()

def menu():
#assigns the menu to menuDisplay
  menuDisplay = print('''
  Welcome! Please make a choice from the following menu

  1. Select a year and display available data
  2. Review averages by year range
  3. Select a date range to display highest
  4. Select a date range to display lowest 
  5. Get total for a selected year range
  6. blank
  7. blank
  8. See this menu again
  9. QUIT the program
''')


def menuInput():
#loops until 9 is selected  
while True:
    try:
      userChoice=int(input('Please make a selection: '))
    except ValueError:
    print('Please enter a whole number less than or equal to 9')

  if userChoice > 9:
    print('Please enter a number less or equal to 9')
  elif userChoice == 0:
    print('Please enter a number greater than 0')
  elif userChoice == 1:
    print('Good')
  elif userChoice == 2:
    print('Good')
  elif userChoice == 3:
    print('Good')
  elif userChoice == 4:
    print('Good')
  elif userChoice == 5:
    print('Good')
  elif userChoice == 6:
    print('Good')
  elif userChoice == 7:
    print('Invalid Choice')
  elif userChoice == 8:
    print('Good')
  else:
    print('Thank you! Program Exiting!')

#Calls main 
main()
```

Comment: You haven't described what the problem is, but your line `except:ValueError` is incorrect, should be `except ValueError:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def main():
#calls menu input
  menuInput()

def menu():
#assigns the menu to menuDisplay
  menuDisplay = print('''
  Welcome! Please make a choice from the following menu

  1. Select a year and display available data
  2. Review averages by year range
  3. Select a date range to display highest
  4. Select a date range to display lowest 
  5. Get total for a selected year range
  6. blank
  7. blank
  8. See this menu again
  9. QUIT the program
''')


def menuInput():
#loops until 9 is selected  
    while True:
        menu()
        try:
            userChoice=int(input('Please make a selection: '))
        except ValueError:
            print('Please enter a whole number less than or equal to 9')

        if userChoice > 9:
            print('Please enter a number less or equal to 9')
        elif userChoice == 0:
            print('Please enter a number greater than 0')
        elif userChoice == 1:
            print('Good')
        elif userChoice == 2:
            print('Good')
        elif userChoice == 3:
            print('Good')
        elif userChoice == 4:
            print('Good')
        elif userChoice == 5:
            print('Good')
        elif userChoice == 6:
            print('Good')
        elif userChoice == 7:
            print('Invalid Choice')
        elif userChoice == 8:
            print('Good')
        else:
            print('Thank you! Program Exiting!')
            exit(1)

#Calls main 
main()
```

You forgot to add exit(1)

Comment: this seems to have helped however, the entire menu should be displayed after each input unless the user entered 9, then the program displays ''Thank you! Program Exiting"

Comment: Your `menu` function that displays the menu is never called in your code.  You could call it at the beginning of your while loop